# How to run mvc controller action from command line

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, command-line, cmd

I can run this php script from command line: php http://localhost/test/test.php 
but when i created this script using mvc controller action, such as in laravel/symfony: and tried to run it from cmd: php http://localhost/test/test

I got the following error: Could not open input file: http://localhost/test/test

how can i run this script from cmd?

Comment: `curl -L http://localhost/test/test.php`

Comment: I think you should create cmd with Php artisan after that call controller action inside of handle function in class that you created above.(in Laravel)

Comment: What is the problem that you try to solve which requires you to execute a full HTTP stack on the command-line?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has the specific structure to build script to run from command line.

Artisan console documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan

Comment: And how to in symfony?

Comment: I don't build anything with Symphony, but I think this will help you
https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html